# Unable to create the directory error

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, war

I created a new subdomain and uploaded the WAR file into its directory, but the server returns following error.

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to create the directory[/home/jack/public_html/WAR/MYWAR]
.....
```

The permission of WAR folder and the WAR file are 0755.

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 jack jack      4096 Feb  2 02:43 ./
drwxr-xr-x 10 jack nobody     4096 Jan 25 01:48 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 jack jack      4096 Jan 24 22:38 cgi-bin/
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jack jack  82135738 Feb  2 02:23 MYWAR.war*
drwxr-xr-x  4 jack jack      4096 Jan 25 01:31 WEB-INF/
```

**ps -aux | grep tomcat**

```
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
root      1239  0.0  0.0 103240   864 pts/2    S+   04:38   0:00 grep tomcat
root      1330  0.0  0.0  10436   352 ?        Ss   Feb01   0:00 jsvc.exec -user tomcat -cp ./bootstrap.jar -Djava.endorsed.dirs=../common/endorsed -outfile ../logs/catalina.out -errfile ../logs/catalina.err -verbose org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
tomcat    1334  0.2 14.9 1566688 151852 ?      Sl   Feb01   1:38 jsvc.exec -user tomcat -cp ./bootstrap.jar -Djava.endorsed.dirs=../common/endorsed -outfile ../logs/catalina.out -errfile ../logs/catalina.err -verbose org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

Comment: And what's the user run this program and the owner of the upper dir where the dir to be created?

Comment: Where can I find out about those?

Comment: ps aux | grep `programm name`, for dir just `ls -al`

Comment: @armnotstrong the output is root      1196  0.0  0.0 103240   864 pts/2    S+   04:35   0:00 grep MYWAR

Comment: try ps -aux | grep tomcat

Comment: @Jack, this is not the right progress, if grep match the program name, there  should be two progress in the output, one is the matched program and the other one is the grep process itself, you just gave the grep process, try `grep -i ` for case incentive match, and I don't think there would be a `MYWAR` substring in the program name, if your run this in a http container, try the container name instead, like `ps aux | grep glassfish` or `ps aux | grep tomcat` like @Reenactor post

Comment: @armnotstrong question is updated thanks

Comment: then try to change the `upper` dir to owner `tomcat` with this `sudo chown tomcat /home/jack/public_html/WAR/ -R`, you should be aware that once execute this command the owner information will be changed and former owner information will be lost, so do this with careful

Comment: what do you mean by owner information will be changed? I suppose I should give write access to tomcat as well. am I right?

Comment: What I mean is once executing `sudo chown tomcat -R` to a specified dir, the owner of the specified dir will be changed and so is the sub dir in that specified dir, recursionly

Comment: @Jack this what I mean

Comment: how to make a group? then I can put myself and tomcat in the group, so I wont loss the control of the folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70018/discussion-between-jack-and-armnotstrong).

Comment: @armnotstrong I followed this question http://superuser.com/questions/280994/give-write-permissions-to-multiple-users-on-a-folder-in-ubuntu and tried to create a new group and added root,tomcat and jack to it then tried to give full access of WAR folder and its subdir to this group. not the server shows drwxr-xr-x  4 jack    775     4096 Feb  2 05:19 WAR/

Comment: Even if you make this work somehow, you should never do it. The directory a war is running from is specifically not guaranteed to be writable, and many servers don't explode the war. Never try to write into the Web application itself.

Comment: @chrylis the server supports 'instant drop and deploy' what do you suggest me to do?

Comment: @Jack I think you have done it wrongly, there shouldn't be a `775` group id, just follow the step I gave you on our chat channel

Comment: It looks SELinux is running on your system. Check /etc/selinux/config (e.g. less less /etc/selinux/config) if there is a line with SELINUX=enforcing or other policy name assignment. Let me know that value. Check also the context of tomcat you're running ( ps -AfZ | grep tomcat )  and context of your WAR directory you want create (ls -Z /home/jack).

Answer (score 8):

0755  is rwxr-xr-x.  If you are not the owner of the directory(it is usally user nobody), you cannot write in the directory. You need to be owner of the directory or root to write in that location.

Comment: Thanks, so how to solve the issue? I just updated the question

Comment: ls -l  will show you perms and owners on linux boxes

Comment: maybe `sudo chmod g+w  the_directory_in_which_you_want_write`? (if you are just in the group of the directory owner: better to allow only to the group that to all the world)

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
sudo chown -R tomcat:tomcat /home/jack/public_html/
```

probably you shouldn't need to change for the entire `public_html`, but you can try to see if it works, and then restrict permissions to your desired folder.

Answer (score 2):

If permission, user and group are correct. Maybe the answer is selinux.

Answer (score 1):

We need to make sure that Tomcat has permission to fully access the folders. Firstly identify what user or group Tomcat is running in. Next grant that user and/or group ownership. For example the following code will change ownership of directory test folder and everything under it:

```
sudo chown -R owner:group /home/blabla/test
```

This will give the owner and group ownership for executing commands.
http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchown.htm

Next we use chmod to grant permission which defines the permissions for the owner of the file (the "user"), members of the group who owns the file (the "group")

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm

Comment: Thanks, please read my comments blew the question, I already added tomcat to a group and gave full access to the group but it has not solved the problem yet.

Comment: @Jack Its unable to create a directory "/home/jack/public_html/WAR/MYWAR". I suspect your "MYWAR" dir already exists and hence fails to create it again. If that is the case, first delete the MYWAR dir.

Comment: No it does not there is just one MYWAR.war file in the dir.

Comment: okay, can you change the permission of the WAR directory to 777 from 775 through chmod and check if it works

Comment: Were you able to do it? Here is the command: sudo chmod 777 /home/jack/public_html/WAR

Answer (score 1):

seems like you need to

give group full access write to the WAR directory

```
sudo chmod 775 /home/jack/public_html/WAR/
```

then change the group of the directory to tomcat

```
chown -R jack:tomcat /home/jack/public_html/WAR/
```

Answer (score 0):

First check permission and ownership of tomcat root directory. In my case /usr/share/tomcat/

**chown -R tomcat:tomcat /usr/share/tomcat**

check selinux.

**getenforce**

if it will return Enforcing set selinux to Permissive

**setenforce 0**

then restart tomcat and reload the app from tomcat. Issue will be resolved.