# Unable to create the directory for webapp in Tomcat in mac

Tags: java, macos, maven, tomcat

I tried to deploy my web app `smart4j` to tomcat 8 server in localhost. It failed with the following message (updated):

```
08-Nov-2015 08:57:42.302 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Nov-2015 08:57:42.309 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
08-Nov-2015 08:57:42.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 867 ms
08-Nov-2015 08:59:31.907 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /Users/minconghuang/Informatique/Java/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/smart4j.war
08-Nov-2015 08:59:36.764 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart Exception fixing docBase for context [/smart4j]
 java.io.IOException: Unable to create the directory [/Users/minconghuang/Informatique/Java/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/smart4j/license]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart(ContextConfig.java:744)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:461)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1526)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1460)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

08-Nov-2015 09:00:02.991 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
08-Nov-2015 09:01:31.692 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error listenerStart
08-Nov-2015 09:01:31.693 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/smart4j] startup failed due to previous errors
08-Nov-2015 09:01:31.781 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [smart4j] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
08-Nov-2015 09:01:31.782 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [smart4j] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
08-Nov-2015 09:01:31.783 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [smart4j] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@3a0f8a4d]) and a value of type [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl] (value [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@25c37603]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
08-Nov-2015 09:01:31.783 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [smart4j] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap] (value [org.apache.log4j.helpers.ThreadLocalMap@5240e302]) and a value of type [java.util.Hashtable] (value [{}]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
08-Nov-2015 09:01:31.790 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /Users/minconghuang/Informatique/Java/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/smart4j.war has finished in 119,883 ms
```

To make sure Tomcat has to permission to write on my mac, I did `chmod 777 webapps` to grant the webapps folder, but it did not help. And here're some useful details.

**The content of webapps folder**:

```
macbook-pro-de-mincong:webapps minconghuang$ ls -l
total 116168
drwxr-xr-x@ 19 minconghuang  staff       646 Mar 23  2015 ROOT
drwxr-xr-x@ 55 minconghuang  staff      1870 Mar 23  2015 docs
drwxr-xr-x@  7 minconghuang  staff       238 Mar 23  2015 examples
drwxr-xr-x@  7 minconghuang  staff       238 Mar 23  2015 host-manager
drwxr-xr-x@  8 minconghuang  staff       272 Mar 23  2015 manager
drwxr-xr-x   5 minconghuang  staff       170 Nov  7 18:05 mvndeploy
-rw-r--r--   1 minconghuang  staff      1693 Nov  7 18:05 mvndeploy.war
-rw-r--r--   1 minconghuang  staff  59472717 Nov  7 20:12 smart4j.war
```

**conf/tomcat-users.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <user username="mincong" password="mincong" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

By the way, I did another deployment test with a simple maven-based project `mvndeploy.war`. And it did expand into a folder. So, am I missing something in my application **smart4j** ?

Comment: Does the tomcat server run as the same user the one which managed to deploy your sample maven app?

Comment: This is a good point ! Tomcat didn't run as the same user. I'll add the `conf/tomcat-users.xml` in my question.

Comment: I was not talking about users declared in Tomcat, I was talking about the system user which runs the Tomcat server; is that `minconghuang`?

Comment: yes, it's `minconghuang`

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure if it's `minconghuang` or `root`. How can I check it ? I start tomcat server with the command line `sh bin/startup.sh` with user `minconghuang`

Comment: After hours tests, I still cannot find out why. But with exactly the same code, I successfully deployed `smart4j` to another computer running on Linux. So I hope one day someone can tell me why it didn't work on Mac :/

Comment: That is most strange. For starters, can you paste the full stack trace? There are only the first two lines here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to create the directory error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271111/unable-to-create-the-directory-error)

Comment: @OrangeDog, my code works in Linux as I mentioned in the comment. The problem is rather related to mac OSX. I'll update the tag to make it more clear. Thanks for your attention.