# How load a external "war" file to the embedded tomcat server of spring boot

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, war

I'm trying to load a "war" file to the embedded tomcat server of Spring boot.
For doing that I found this answer:
[Spring Boot: How to add another WAR files to the embedded tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374726/spring-boot-how-to-add-another-war-files-to-the-embedded-tomcat)

But after I do that, I found the same error already asked on this question:
[Deploying existing war with embedded Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529282/deploying-existing-war-with-embedded-tomcat) but 
without a satisfactory answer.

**NOTE**: I know it can be seen as a duplicate question (I put the link), but not having at the time enough reputation for add a comment, or the ability to contact the author in private, i have seen the need to repeat the question hoping for some different answer.

In particular I'm try to load the [Sesame](http://rdf4j.org/) war files allocated on "resources/war/" folder of the spring boot project.

My SpringBootapplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.github.p4535992.mvc")
public class JspDemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(JspDemoApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(JspDemoApplication.class);
}

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    SpringApplication.run(JspDemoApplication.class);
}

/*
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374726/spring-boot-how-to-add-another-war-files-to-the-embedded-tomcat
 * @return the {@link TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory}.
 */
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainerFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(Tomcat tomcat) {
            try {
                //tomcat.addUser("tomcat", "tomcat");
                //tomcat.addRole("tomcat", "manager-gui");
                String webappDirLocation = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/resources/war/";
                //When the spring boot application is made of fat jar(=executable jar),
                // the above code is not enough             
                Context context1 = tomcat.addWebapp("/sesame", new
                        File(webappDirLocation+"openrdf-sesame.war").getAbsolutePath());
                Context context2 =  tomcat.addWebapp("/workbench",new
                        File(webappDirLocation+"openrdf-workbench.war").getAbsolutePath());
                WebappLoader loader = new WebappLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
                context1.setLoader(loader);
                context2.setLoader(loader);

            } catch (ServletException ex) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to add webapp", ex);
            }
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }

    };
}
}
```

My Old Exception: [old_exception](http://pastebin.com/SkkZfcXm)

**UPDATE**:

**NOTE**: I work on Windows just to clarify.

1. Add to the application.properties file the argument : *server.tomcat.basedir=${java.io.tmpdir}*.
2. Set the JAVA_OPTIONS: *-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\path\springMVC12\Temp*.
3. Manually create the directory *"sesame"* and *"workbench"* on the "Temp" directory (for more details or other way to do that see comment of OrangeDog)
4. Create a class AppConfig.java with @Configuration Spring Annotation, cut and paste the method "EmbeddedServletContainerFactory" from JspDemoApplication.java to AppConfig.java.

Now no exception is thrown, but when i try to call the webapp on the address
http://localhost:8081/openrdf-sesame , http://localhost:8081/sesame , i get the error 404 resource not found.

e.g. *"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available"*

So now it's seems the war file is loaded, but i must miss something on the set of the http url of the web app.

**UPDATE 2**
The new Application.java of Spring Boot:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.github.p4535992.mvc")

public class MainApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(MainApp.class);
}

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    //com.github.p4535992.mvc.component.ScheduledTasks --> Work
    SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class);
}

@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainerFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(Tomcat tomcat) {
            try {
                String webappDirLocation = "src/main/resources/war/";
                tomcat.addWebapp("/sesame", new
                        File(webappDirLocation+"openrdf-sesame.war").getAbsolutePath());
                tomcat.addWebapp("/workbench",new
                        File(webappDirLocation+"openrdf-workbench.war").getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (ServletException ex) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to add webapp", ex);
            }
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }

    };
}
}
```

NOw i have a new exception:

```
2016-04-09_10:25:01.998 [Tomcat-startStop-1] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase - A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatResources$Tomcat7Resources.addJar(TomcatResources.java:125)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatResources.addClasspathResources(TomcatResources.java:63)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory$StoreMergedWebXmlListener.onStart(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:746)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory$StoreMergedWebXmlListener.lifecycleEvent(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:737)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatResources$Tomcat7Resources.addJar(TomcatResources.java:122)
... 13 common frames omitted
2016-04-09_10:06:32.378 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/sesame] - Servlet [jsp] in web application [/sesame] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:499)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4997)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5289)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-04-09_10:06:32.568 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/workbench] - Servlet [jsp] in web application [/workbench] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:499)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4997)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5289)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I try to resolve the issue adding the maven dependency but it doesn't work:

```
 <!-- Support for add war to the project -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.M4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501829/unable-to-load-class-for-jsp -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2-b02</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Any help is more then welcome.

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of the question you have linked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to create the directory error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271111/unable-to-create-the-directory-error)

Comment: OK, that can be the solution but how can accomplish that on a windows machine?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42052345/how-can-i-deploy-a-war-file-to-the-built-in-tomcat-server-of-a-spring-boot-appli)) but I don't think it's a permission issue. Did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: sorry man no after all this time , i haven't find a solution for this

Answer (score 1):

> i found the same error already asked on this question: Deploying existing war with embedded Tomcat but without a satisfactory answer.

Because such configuration doesn't make sense for Spring Boot. You have two options with Spring Boot:

1. WAR, deployed on shared and managed servlet container
2. fat JAR, where your single application will be running on single embedded servlet container

[Read this section of Spring Boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) for more info.

Also notice that question you are referring to is not Spring/Spring Boot related.

Comment: Sorry lubo I have to be really stupid, I read the documentation but I can not find the solution that interests me, would you be so kind as to give me an example?